# Jquery onclick on parent div doesn't work on img child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple code with an image in a div

When I click on the div but not on the image (with padding for example), it works, but when I click on the image, it does not work.

```js
$(".parent0").click(function() {
  console.log("hello");
});
```

```css
div { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black; width: 655px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent0">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-640-480-6.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me once I created a snippet and added jQuery to it. You do not need to close the img tag however.. next time create a [mcve] and perhaps you will see what you missed

Comment: try like this
$("div").on("click", ".parent0", function(){
}
});

Comment: @Shibon why would he do that? Your edit does not make it any better.

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: is it inside a `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs obviously or it would not work on either div or img

Comment: @mplungjan not always true - could be a window.onload :p I'm just trying to get a better understanding of how it's all set up :) it could be triggered from an external $.fn function - many possibilities that would allow it to work without document.ready :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have it so that it's the click on the image that does something, rather than the div? Since the div itself is just code containing the image which is what is shown.

Add an id to the image and listen for it to be clicked or add onclick (think that works on images as well?) to the image which calls a function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent0">
  <img id="imageClick" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-640-480-6.jpg"></img>
</div>


$("#imageClick").click(function() {
  console.log("hello");
});
```

or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent0">
  <img onclick=DoFunction() src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-640-480-6.jpg"></img>
</div>

function DoFunction(){
do something
};
```

Comment: I would never recommend inline js - move to external script :)

Comment: Yeah i agree. Was just typing an example. Put the js down at the bottom of the file, ofc! :)

Comment: ofc! haha just making sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:
I have another div after with position relative and width:100%, 
its cover my image, so i put z-index:2 to my div parent0.

Its fine :)

Thank you all.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question - it is not useful to people coming after

Answer (score -1):

you made mistake in the image tag . You tag will be like

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-640-480-6.jpg" />
```

Comment: I already commented that - it is not the source of the problem

Comment: Sorry Mate , i will remember in future. Thanks